# Blender Displace Modifier not importing into Unity

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, unity

I created an animation using the Displace Modifier. There is a keyframe for the strength.

This animation does not show up when I import it into Unity (as a .fbx and as a .blend). Does Unity not support this kind of animation?

Thanks!

Comment: you can export using shape keys for animation. better look at this tutorial
https://youtu.be/wvjwTnS6vhA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you won't be able to export that. There's no support for vertex animation/morph targets in Unity. You can only import bone-based animated objects.